# docker/podman issue when building in a golang:1.20 container

Tags: docker, selinux, podman

Anyone know why podman fails and docker works?

podman:

```
$ podman run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp golang:1.20 go build -v
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
```

docker:

```
$ sudo docker  run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp golang:1.20 go build -v
go: downloading github.com/spf13/cobra v1.7.0
go: downloading github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.5
go: downloading gopkg.in/op/go-logging.v1 v1.0.0-20160211212156-b2cb9fa56473
go: downloading github.com/a8m/envsubst v1.4.2
go: downloading github.com/alecthomas/participle/v2 v2.0.0
go: downloading github.com/dimchansky/utfbom v1.1.1
.. and so on resulting in an artefact
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of checking gave that the container user did not have read access to the mounted volume:

```
$ podman run --rm  -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp golang:1.20 /bin/bash -c "id; ls -l /usr/src/; ls -l /usr/src/myapp"
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 12 root root 4096 Jul 19 10:19 myapp
ls: cannot open directory '/usr/src/myapp': Permission denied
```

This in turn gave me som additional google material that lead me to this answer on [devops.stackexchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/11267/33874)

**tl;dr answer**

- I have selinux enabled on my host that gives permission problems
- Change `-v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp` to `-v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp:z`

Some more reading about this `:z` can be found here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/651198/2298

Comment: Even more info https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/user-namespaces-selinux-rootless-containers